# When caching identities, should it be Singleton or Scoped?

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

When caching identity information for multiple kinds of users, specially where key conflict in a single cache object may happen, I usually partition the cache by creating custom cache classes:

```
public BackEndUserCache: MemoryCache {
  ...
}
public FrontEndUserCache: MemoryCache {
  ...
}
```

I've been thinking for quite a while about whether I have to inject the dependencies as Singleton or Scoped?

To clarify:

1- I think that if I bind these to `IMemoryCache` as Singleton, there may be a security flaw as the credentials for all users will be cached in a single global cache list.

2- If I bind it in a Scoped way, the cache object will be created per each connection, and will be expired which the session is terminated. But would this make sense when caching?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by inheriting from MemoryCache?

Comment: As a general rule, pretty much every dependency in a web application should be request-scoped (or just "Scoped" in ASP.NET Core parlance). If you're going to use singleton-scope, you need to 100% sure whatever the dependency does is completely thread-safe, which is a pretty high bar.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: The memory cache as stated by Microsoft is thread-safe.

Answer (score -1):

For any user specific data use a `scoped` cache. Create another `singleton` cache service class for common data such as Countries, ZipCodes, Products etc.

Therefore you would need **two Interfaces, `IScopedCacheService` and `ISingletonCacheService`**

```
public class ScopedCacheService : IScopedCacheService
{
    private IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    public ScopedCacheService (IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
    ...
}
```

}

Similar implementation for SingletonCacheService class. And you can register them in Services in following way:

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSingleton<IScopedCacheService, ScopedCacheService>();
services.AddSingleton<ISingletonCacheService, SingletonCacheService>();
```